# logging logs continuously from Python script into one single document of MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, logging, pymongo

I'm trying to use ***logging*** module to write my logs directly to MongoDB. I figured out there's a way to use logging module along with ***log4mongo*** module of MongoDB. Below is the sample code I wrote -

```
import logging
from log4mongo.handlers import MongoHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.addHandler(MongoHandler(host='localhost', database_name='logs', collection='sample', 
reuse=True))
logger.warning("This is a sample log message", extra={"ID":1})
logger.warning("This is a sample extra log message", extra={"ID":1})
```

The issue with this is, it creates two documents inside the `sample` collection with `"ID":1`. However, what I really wish is to write both the logs to the same document along with the field `"ID:":1`.

Is there a way to achieve this in Python + MongoDB? `BufferedMongoHandler` doesn't serve my purpose as it performs timed insertion of logs which is not what I require.

Comment: That's not really an option with the implementation of the module you are using. If you want something else you could always write your own custom logger implementation. That module really does nothing more that `insert` a new document for each logging entry, along with marking the *type* ( warn, info, etc ). That's pretty much the standard behavior for *"loggers"*, so your expectation is different from what people normally do.

Comment: @NeilLunn is there a standard or recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: The "recommendation" I would give is that "logging" really *should* be exactly what is currently happening, as in **one** document per logging statement, just as it would be **one** line in a text file. That has pretty much been industry practice for a very long time. If "you" want to do things differently, then you're welcome to do your own thing. But it's just not how it's generally done.

Comment: @NeilLunn I guess "you" are not clear with what I asked for. I don't wanna log data in chunks or buffer, all I want is it's logged to one single document, instead of one line per document, just like it "is" done in text file logs. logging adds log information as and when it's called to the specified file, it does "not" create **one** file per line of log, i.e. every logging information content, to the "same" file.

Comment: It is however not possible with log4mongo. What you can do is subclass the `MongoHandler` and change its `emit` method to what you want it to do.

Comment: Alright. Let me look into it. Thanks @blues